# Cassandra- map reduce functionality on windows machine

Tags: windows, mapreduce, cassandra

I am new to cassandra and I need to implement map-reduce functionality to achieve aggregate functionality.

please let me know steps to do it. I have `cassandra 2.0` on `windows` machine. I have gone through `word_count` example but didn't understand that do I need to install hadoop as a pre-requisite for this.

Comment: Put some code, what you try...

Comment: Are you asking, "How do I install Hadoop on Windows?"